# Grails 3: Integration tests run at a development environment, not at a test environment

Tags: grails, grails-3.1

I have separated `dataSourceConfig.yml` database config file:

```
environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: none
            url: jdbc:oracle:thin:xxxxxx
            driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
            dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
            username: xxxx
            password: xxxx
    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: none
            url: jdbc:oracle:thin:xxxxx
            driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
            dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
            username: xxxxx
            password: xxxxx
```

Which I connect to the project in the `Application.java`:

```
class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration implements EnvironmentAware {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        GrailsApp.run(Application, args)
    }

    @Override
    void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        String configPath = environment.getProperty("local.config.location")
        Resource resourceConfig = new FileSystemResource(configPath)
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean ypfb = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean()
        ypfb.setResources([resourceConfig] as Resource[])
        ypfb.afterPropertiesSet()
        Properties properties = ypfb.getObject()

        environment.propertySources.addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("local.config.location", properties))
    }
 }
```

When i run integration tests via Intellij IDEA 15, it runs tests at a **development** environment, but the YAML config file has **test** section.

Is anyone knows how to fix this? 
The command bellow doesn't help.

```
grails test test-app -integration
```

Comment: What happens if you run `grails -Dgrails.env=test test-app -clean -integration`?

Comment: @saw303 When running the tests using `grails` or `gradle` you should not need to specify `-Dgrails.env=test`.  That should only be required when running from the IDE using the IDE's built in run config stuff.

Comment: `grails test test-app -integration` isn't valid.  You probably want `grails test-app integration:` or `./gradlew iT`.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown 
"To run integration tests you would run...
grails test-app -integration "
from [Grails 3.1.4 docs](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/testing.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are going to run tests from the IDE you need to modify the run config to include `-Dgrails.env=test`.  You will want to do that for the default JUnit run config so you don't have to edit every single test run config.  Be aware that editing the default JUnit run config will affect all configs that are created in the future but will not update any existing configs.  You may want to remove all of the existing run configs so they will be recreated with the new settings the next time you run those tests.

Comment: I am talking about the run configuration within the IDE, not anything that you specify in a Grails configuration file.